# slimframework request->headers don´t read Authorization

Tags: rest, http-headers, authorization, slim

i´m trying to implement a simple authorization with slim on serverside and angularJS on client side. For Testing the REST APi i´m using a program called Rested for Mac which allows to send rest calls.

I want to deliver, once authorization has completed, at each rest call an jwt token which can than be used within slim to authorize requests for certain paths.

Now i deliver via Rested the following header and body:

```
Accept: */* 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: jwt-test 
Accept-Language: de-de

{ 
  "login": "TestLogin", 
  "password": "TestPassword", 
  "uuid": "dsfglj45690dfgkl456" 
}
```

And than just print out the whole header:

```
Slim\Http\Headers Object ( [data:protected] => Array ( [Host] => localhost:8888 
[Content-Type] => application/json [Content-Length] => 89 [Connection] 
=> keep-alive [Accept] => */* [User-Agent] => Rested/2009 CFNetwork/673.4 
Darwin/13.4.0 (x86_64) (iMac13%2C2) [Accept-Language] => de-de [Accept-Encoding] 
=> gzip, deflate ) )
```

As you can see, there is no Authorization within this array.

I also checked this with firefox directly, same results. O can see Authorization string within the request headers with firebug, but it is not in the dumped array at slimframework.

Does anyone has a hint where my problem lies?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

solick

Comment: How are you adding the login headers? What you shared looks like a request body, not headers. Also, as an aside, it's a **really** bad idea to ever send a password in plain text, whether in request headers or otherwise.

Comment: No, i will use jwt later on, isßs just for testing. I only add the authorization to the header, not more. As you can see, if is the header object Slim\Http\Headers

Comment: Please share a code sample showing how you're setting those headers. We'll be better able to give you a hand that way.

Comment: As i described i tested with a mac program which generates rest api calls by defining the header field 'Authorization' with the value'jwt-test'. The second test was within my angularjs application where i use an interceptor to add to each request the Authorization header with: config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.tokenUUID;

Comment: I have a similar issue. Could you check at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107875/generate-jwt-with-user-information

Answer (score 26):

## Problem

Basic authentication header should look something like this.

```
Authorization: Basic cm9vdDp0MDBy
```

The string after Basic is constructed by combining username and password into a string like `username:password`. Resulting string is then encoded using base64.

You are sending header to webserver which PHP will not parse. Not sure if this is considered bug or a feature.

```
Authorization: jwt-test
```

## Solution

With current version of Slim if you add the following to .htaccess file.

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

You can then access even non standard header with any of these.

```php
var_dump($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]);
var_dump(apache_request_headers()["Authorization"]);
var_dump($app->request->headers("Authorization"));
```

It gives the following result:

```
string 'jwt-test' (length=8)
string 'jwt-test' (length=8)
string 'jwt-test' (length=8)
```

You could also use some other header name such as `X-Authorization`.

Comment: Hi Mika, thanks for the explanations. As far as i understand you, Apache expect a special format for the Authorization value to be accepted? Can you share some link where this is defined? I tried in my angularJS application with config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.tokenUUID; But still i can not see the Authorization field when i dump the headers object.

Comment: Thanks Mika. Unfortunately i had to stop because of another project. I hope i will be able to return to this project next week and try ti implement your solution.

Comment: @Mika Tuuplola I tried your answer but not work. Printing all headers does not show Authorization header. i am using nginx

Answer (score 1):

Because I struggled with this too, here is what I found as described [here in the Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#get-all-headers), without the need to add anything to the .htaccess file

```php
$request->getHeader("Authorization");
```